# Calculating the next number in the sequence

Tags: contest-math

I want to know the next number in the sequence below:

1935, 1940, 1948, 1962, 1985, 2020, …

Consecutive differences are 5, 8, 14, 23, 35

They don't look like Fib-seq. Also consecutive differences of the consecutive differences increase rapidly!

This is from math olympiad for middle school students. There are 4 options : 2070, 2055, 2060, 2067.

Comment: Any suggestions?  Ask questions that can actually be answered.  Questions of the form "what is the next number in the sequence" are entirely subjective.  *Any* number can be the next and there is nothing that should suggest otherwise.  It may as well be that the next number is $42$ and you can't prove me wrong.

Comment: @JMoravitz I edited my post

Comment: Notice that there is a pattern in the second differences, $3,6,9,12,\cdots$. Does that correspond to one of the possible answers?

Comment: I put in in OEIS and it said: Your sequence appears to be: $+ \frac12 x^3 − \frac32 x^2 + 6 x + 1930$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find the consecutive difference of the consecutive differences you can see there is a pattern.

$1935, 1940, 1948, 1962, 1985, 2020$

consecutive differences are

$5,8,14,23,35$

consecutive differences of these consecutive differences

$3,6,9,12$

consecutive differences of those consecutive differences

$3,3,3$

assuming these 3s don't change the next number in the sequence is 2070.

Interestingly, if you subtract 1/2 n^3, you will cancel out these common differences and will be left with a quadratic sequence. By performing a similar process with the cube numbers, can you work out why this is the case?